# Нужно добавить в state объект и проверить нет ли таких же объектов в React

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

У меня есть стейт

```
this.state = {
            meal : [
                {type: null,             
            budget: null,        
            key: 0
                }
            ],  
            randomMeal: {
            type: null,             
            budget: null,        
            key: null
            },
        }
```

Я ролучаю из апи данные, записываю в randomMeal, если пользователь согласен с блюдом, при нажатии на кнопку записываю уже в стейт meal.
Мне нужно проверить, есть ли блюда с похожими ключами. если нет, записываем, если да, пропускаем. А также самое первое блюдо нужно перезаписать в meal, т.к. там сейчас нулевые данные. Не получается с проверкой по ключу. первое блюдо перезаписывается, а остальные не проверяются. и одно блюдо может записываться несколько раз.

```
addItem = (randomMeal) => {
        let newItem = {
            type: randomMeal.type,            
            budget: randomMeal.budget,
            key: randomMeal.key
        }
        
        const {meal : [{key}]} = this.state; 
         
  if (key === 0) {
      return  this.setState({ meal: [{...newItem}]});  
    }      

if (newItem.key !== key ) {
        this.setState(({meal}) => {
            const newMeal = [...meal, newItem];
            
            return {
                meal: newMeal
            }
        });
   }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашла решение, пропустила через find

```
const index = this.state.meal.find(item => item.key === newItem.key);
if (!index) { проверка }
```